# How can I remove ESET nod32 locked registry entries from windows 7 32bit after uninstallation?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I uninstalled ESET smart security from my windows 7 32bit,but the leftovers causing problem now installing other antivirus programme.I've tried to delete the redundant entries,but failed.Plz help me.

Comment: You should probably add more details on the problem you are facing (possibly with details on error messages, if any), so that others can get a better idea on the issue and offer solutions/suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

Try running an ESET Uninstaller.  It can be located here along with detailed instructions on how to run it.  This should delete all signs of the old ESET installation and allow you to start anew with a new AV program of your choice.

http://kb.eset.com/esetkb/index?page=content&id=SOLN2289

1. Download the ESET Uninstaller (650 KB) and save it to your Desktop.
2. Restart your computer in Safe Mode.
3. Click Start>All Programs>Accessories. Right-click Command Prompt and choose Run as administrator from the context menu.
4. In the command prompt window type cd Desktop and press Enter.

   - In some cases, the ESET Uninstaller utility will need to be launched by typing ESETUninstaller.exe /reinst into the command line and pressing Enter (see Figure 1-4). The ESET Uninstaller utility will prompt you if the above switch is necessary.
   - If you are prompted to use the ESETUninstaller.exe /reinst command, your Network Interface Card settings will be reset. We recommend that you record your network settings somewhere so that you can easily reconfigure them after running the uninstaller tool.
5. Read the warning and type y to confirm.
6. Review the item(s) listed under Installed AV products, type the number that corresponds to the ESET installation in this list that you want to remove and then press Enter.
7. Verify that you are uninstalling the correct ESET product from the correct operating system and type y to confirm.
8. Once the ESET Uninstaller tool is finished running, press any key to exit and then restart your computer in normal mode.

   - The uninstaller writes a log of all its processes to the ~ESETUninstaller.log file (located in the same folder as the ESETUnistaller.exe file) for future reference.

Comment: Its customary on SuperUser to copy/paste as much text as possible in answers in case the link dies. For that reason I will not vote up your answer. If you edit your answer and include the removal instructions and a direct link too, I will vote this up. Having a source link is good though...

Comment: @LPChip I wasn't sure if I should put all that in the answer, but I get your point, it's all added!  Thanks for the tip to help improve my answers!

Comment: Nice. Voted up. :)